# free Website testing tool

Tags: c#, python, ruby

I am eager to know about any website testing software which is good in usability and look and feel.
Here are the main areas that software should cover.
1. Find the image size.
2. To check broken links.
3. Loading time of website.
4. Test the load with many virtual users.
5. Check for useless codes placed in the source code.

In short, I want all these things cover under one software....

Mayank

Answer (score 3):

I recommend [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) for frontend testing.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly won't find these requirements wrapped in one app - although I'm sure you could build a test script for this.

That been said, take a look at [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) for load testing (very flexible app once you've get the hang of it), [Xenu](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html) for link checking. There are tools available that can check code quality to some degree, but they're obviously language specific. [FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476(VS.80).aspx) (for .NET) is one example.

Answer (score 1):

If you are Firefox user, try [Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60) (kit for nearly everything) and [Pinger](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10201) (extremely fast link checker developed by my colleague) addons.